# Get the evaluated HTML code from a template in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, I want to store the HTML code outputted from `render` into a database.

For example, this is the content of a template (`app/views/mailer/someview.html.erb`):

```
Hello <%= @foo %>.
```

And I would like to store "`Hello Jim.`" in my database by providing the template (`mailer/someview`) and the variables to replace (`:foo => "bar"`).

Is there any way I can do this in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `render_to_string`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it existed!